# Importing a function with useContext gives 'usecontext hook Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call'

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am attempting to update a context state on input change. I want to have a reusable function for this.

My function:

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import NewUserState from "../context/NewUserState";

const updateUserState = (e) => {
  const [setNewUserState] = useContext(NewUserState);
  setNewUserState((current) => {
    const updateUser = { ...current.updateUser };
    updateUser[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    return { ...current, updateUser };
  });
}; 
export default updateUserState;
```

My component:

```
import updateUserState from "../helpers/updateUserState";

const UserDetails = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <form>
            <label htmlFor="first-name">First Name*</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="first-name"
              name="first_name"
              onChange={updateUserState}
            />
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
export default UserDetails;
```

I get the error: `Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

Comment: you are breaking the rules of Hooks

because you are calling useContext in event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You use useConext hook in the return statement of the component.

```js
const UserDetails = () => {
  const [setNewUserState] = useContext(NewUserState);

  const onChange = (e) => setNewUserState((current) => {
    const updateUser = { ...current.updateUser };
    updateUser[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    return { ...current, updateUser };
  });

  return (
    <>
      <form>
        <label htmlFor="first-name">First Name*</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="first-name"
          name="first_name"
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
```

If this is a function that you know that you will use all over the place, you could add the function to the context instead.

Comment: I do need to use it all over the place, what do you mean by "add the function to the context"? Thanks.

Comment: I dont know how your context look like, but you can add the `updateUserState` function to the context and pass it as you do with `setNewUserState `